# LOPG/Deep Space Gateway - What is a cislunar orbit?

Tags: nasa, lunar-gateway

Formerly the Deep Space Gateway and now the [Lunar Orbital Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Orbital_Platform-Gateway) or LOPG station, is planned for Expedition 1 aka the maiden launch of the SLS. After reading several specifications, to avoid the "gravity well" of earth the station will remain on a cislunar orbit. Some sources say that the station will be equipped with electric propulsion systems to adjust orbits, around the earth and the moon.

What is a cislunar orbit, and with this sort of orbit, could the station also orbit the earth with minor burns, and how would this work for rendezvous and docking?

Comment: For some related information (not necessarily a duplicate), see [Why is a near rectilinear halo orbit proposed for LOP-G (formerly known as Deep Space Gateway?)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23992/12102) as well as [What is a near rectilinear halo orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24019/12102)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "cislunar orbit". There is, however, such a thing as "cislunar space", which is nicely described in Hobbes' answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cislunar space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space#Cislunar_space) is a large area:

> The region outside Earth's atmosphere and extending out to just beyond the Moon's orbit, including the Lagrangian points, is sometimes referred to as cis-lunar space.

Earth orbits, Moon orbits and orbits around both (like Apollo 13's free return trajectory) can all be called cislunar orbits.

[LOP-G would](http://www.leonarddavid.com/lunar-orbital-platform-gateway-setting-a-science-agenda/) use a [halo](https://www.space.com/39985-nasa-lunar-orbital-platform-gateway-science-plan.html) orbit:

[image]

> Such orbits, which make close passes by the moon and loop far out, have the advantage of being near the moon, but always keep a station within the line of sight of flight controllers on Earth, as well as in sunlight for solar arrays.

Comment: For these elliptical orbits, how will rendezvous and docking occur for refueling and crew transportation etc?

Comment: I personally wouldn't consider geosynchronous satellites to be operating in cislunar space.

Comment: @MattSmallwood, I wonder that in a similar way as two-body problem rendezvous... with a well characterisation of the periods for the surrounding halo orbits close to the target one, typical phasing strategies can still be applied

Comment: @Julio Surely the ship would have to match the elliptical orbit to match the relative velocity to properly rendezvous and dock? Of course this would be very expensive fuel wise...

Comment: Yes, that's the condition for rendezvous to happen. As a matter of fact, reaching the orbit with the current launchers is one of the drivers to choose that particular place, see: Why is a near rectilinear halo orbit proposed for LOP-G (formerly known as Deep Space Gateway?. Anyway, close rendezvous operations are typically just a small fraction of the total mission fuel cost.