# What are Spectr-R's major contributions to radio astronomy that could not have been done from Earth?

Tags: space-telescope, spektr-r, radio-astronomy

[R. I. P. Spektr-R](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37615/12102)

---

[Spektr-R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spektr-R) Spektr-R  (`37755, 2011-037A`) is a Russian radiotelescope spacecraft in a very high orbit around the Earth. It's orbit is cis-lunar with an [apoapsis of about 300 000 km](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23311/12102).

From [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32475/12102):

> ### Spektr-R
>
> From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spektr-R):
>
> Spektr-R's orbit allows it to get as far from Earth as possible in order to produce a long baseline for [Very Long Baseline Interferometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very-long-baseline_interferometry) (VLBI)
>
> > Spektr-R (or RadioAstron) is a Russian **scientific satellite with a 10 m (33 ft) radio telescope on board**. It was launched on 18 July 2011,[7] by Zenit-3F launcher, from Baikonur Cosmodrome to perform research on the structure and dynamics of radio sources within and beyond our galaxy. Together with some of the largest ground-based radio telescopes, **this telescope forms interferometric baselines extending up to 350,000 km (220,000 mi).**

@BowlofRed's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27188/12102) links to [Radioastron User Handbook](http://www.asc.rssi.ru/radioastron/documents/rauh/en/rauh.pdf) which is full of goodies.

[image]

I've used it in an example in the (currently unanswered) question [What is the largest antenna deployed in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32884/12102)

Currently Spektr-R is [in the news](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-46849347) because of a technical issue, (as is and was recently Hubble) but this question is about the years of observational radioastronomy that *has been done*.

**Question:** What are Spectr-R's major contributions to radio astronomy that could not have been done from Earth?

The answer would not have to be as elaborate as @Hobbes' [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32929/12102) to *What kind of ground-based radio astronomy is NASA's DSN used for? Who are the PIs?*

Comment: Seems like it would better be asked on https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @horsh It's a toss-up because my question focusses on the history of a specific satellite with a particularly interesting orbit, and considering I received such an excellent answer to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32911/12102) here, I decided to ask this particular question here. I have [plenty of radio astronomy questions in Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A7982+%5Bradio-astronomy%5D) as well and have some idea which questions do and don't get answered there. If your experience there is different, let me know.

Comment: The Spectr-R satellite is apparently no longer functioning: https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-46849347

Comment: @42- Thanks! It seems that's the same article I've linked to in the question, and probably what induced me to ask the question the next day. Nonetheless you've convinced me to ask [How is Spektr-R doing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35641/12102)