# What forces and motion would astronauts experience in a spacecraft in Earth-Moon L1 & L2 Lissajous orbit?

Tags: orbit, acceleration, astronauts

What is the maximum velocity they would experience?  Would they be aware of the movement based on the positions of the Earth, Moon, or stars, or would  it be too slow to notice?  Would they feel any G forces?  Would they experience a uniform acceleration about the orbit, would G forces in remain same throughout the orbit, or would the G-forces vary depending on the crafts location in the orbit?

Comment: Speed is not constant in an elliptical orbit, but there is zero gravity for the complete orbit. Why should there any G-force to experience within a lissajous orbit?

Comment: Except for subtle tidal effects, the astronauts are in basically the same orbit as their ship. So it doesn't matter what orbit they are in, they won't notice any substantial accelerations unless they turn on some propulsion for station-keeping.

Comment: Right, the astronaut is also in the orbit.  I had not thought that out correctly.  At L1 would they be moving fast enough so the view of the Moon or the Earth changes enough to be perceptible?

Comment: @Bob516 now that's a very interesting question! I'd recommend you edit this question and add that in, or change to that completely, or ask it as a new question.  You might specify the the near-rectilinear halo orbits that are planned for the NASA proposed station, since it's a particularly unusual orbit. For more on that see: [What is a near rectilinear halo orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24019/12102) and also [Why is a near rectilinear halo orbit proposed for LOP-G (formerly known as Deep Space Gateway?)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23992/12102)