# How do I calculate the characteristic energy for a rocket to near rectilinear halo orbit where the Deep Space Gateway is going to orbit the Moon?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, payload, lunar-gateway

How do I calculate the *characteristic energy* for a rocket to *near rectilinear halo orbit* (NRHO) where the LOP-G or the Deep Space Gateway is going to be orbiting the Moon? Or if someone already has a number, it would be appreciated!!

I am trying to find the payloads different rockets can take to the NRHO. I already have the C3 vs payload mass plots for the rockets I want. I just need the exact amount of C3 required to get there. I know it will be negative, since we are not leaving Earth SOI. Thank you for any and all help. Sources are appreciated.

Comment: You may also be interested in reading answers to [Why is a near rectilinear halo orbit proposed for LOP-G (formerly known as Deep Space Gateway?)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23992/12102) as well as [What is a near rectilinear halo orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24019/12102) for some excellent references and discussion.  I think you will find that transfers from LEO to lunar halo orbits is a really interesting topic!

Comment: @rghome don't forget that the "M" in "the Moon" is capitalized!

Comment: @uhoh done! (plus other case changes).

Answer (score 2):

Reading the linked questions, answers, and references (thanks @uhoh), particularly R. Whitley and R. Martinez, 2015, [Options for Staging Orbits in Cis-Lunar Space](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20150019648.pdf) and this figure:
[image: NRO transfer cost]

Leads me to believe that getting to a NRHO is much like an 'Apollo-style' lunar transfer (i.e., in plane, Hohmann-ish transfer orbit). The only difference comes in targeting the lunar flyby over one of the poles to displace the spacecraft out of the Earth-Moon plane (*hence the term* 'halo') and the 'capture' burn into the NRHO is slowing the spacecraft down (from its lunar escape trajectory). This removes a lot of 3-body dynamics shenanigans from the problem.

A good, quick way to calculate the required C3 is to pretend your rocket is performing a Hohmann transfer to the Moon's (average) orbital distance, 384400 km. From a 250 km low Earth parking orbit:

$$C3=-\frac{GM}{a}, a=\frac{6378km+250km+384400km}{2}=195514km$$
$$C3=-2.0\frac{km^2}{s^2}$$

I recall a professor (whose graduate research was designing lunar landers) saying a C3 value of $-1\frac{km^2}{s^2}$ is commonly used in early analyses.

This [Apollo By the Numbers](https://web.archive.org/web/20041118103812/https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_18-24_Translunar_Injection.htm) archived webpage (linked from the [TLI Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-lunar_injection)) has the Apollo C3 data (converted to nice units):

| Mission | C3 ($\frac{km^2}{s^2}$) |
| --- | --- |
| Apollo 8 | -1.5 |
| Apollo 10 | -1.3 |
| Apollo 11 | -1.4 |
| Apollo 12 | -1.8 |
| Apollo 13 | -1.4 |
| Apollo 14 | -1.7 |
| Apollo 15 | -1.5 |
| Apollo 16 | -1.6 |
| Apollo 17 | -1.7 |

I don't know where you got the performance information but I hope it is [NASA Launch Services Program Launch Vehicle Performance Website](https://elvperf.ksc.nasa.gov/Pages/Default.aspx) and [the SLS mission planner's guide](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20190000736.pdf). Side note, [New Glenn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Glenn) and [Vulcan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_Centaur) are now on the NLSP performance website!

Comment: Cool, so that's how they'll enter orbit.