# How does a butterfly orbit move in 3D? Way to generate or visualize?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, halo-orbit, cislunar, three-body

The paper [Earth-Moon Near Rectilinear Halo and Butterfly Orbits for Lunar Surface Exploration](https://engineering.purdue.edu/people/kathleen.howell.1/Publications/Conferences/2018_AAS_WhiDavBurMcCPowMcGHow.pdf) (AAS 18-406) says

> Periodic Orbits in the Earth-Moon System
>
> The current investigation focuses on three types of periodic orbits in the vicinity of the Moon: Near Rectilinear Halo Orbits (NRHOs), which are periodic in the Earth-Moon rotating frame in the CR3BP; butterfly orbits, a periodic family that bifurcates off the NRHOs; and circular Low Lunar Orbits (LLOs), which are periodic in a Keplerian sense.

and shows the drawing below. There are several questions and answers here about near-rectilinear halo orbits and the ever-so-popular YouTube video [Near Rectilinear Halo Orbit Explained and Visualized](https://youtu.be/X5O77OV9_ek) Okay, I like it at least.

But I can't understand nor visualize what these butterfly orbits look like in 3D or how objects move in them. Is it possible to generate one and show it here with a few views, or to find a resource where this is done, or even to just provide an algorithm and a python script that makes them? Even a set of initial state vectors would be enough to get started.

---

- [What is a near rectilinear halo orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24019/12102)
- [Why is a near rectilinear halo orbit proposed for LOP-G (formerly known as Deep Space Gateway?)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23992/12102)

---

[image: Figure 1: L2 Family of NRHOs and Butterflies]

> Figure 1: L<sub>2</sub> Family of NRHOs and Butterflies

Comment: There's what I feel (despite the poor reproduction quality) to be a clearer [diagram](https://d3i71xaburhd42.cloudfront.net/09aa2393a9f072e03da99336fb82e3ce27998be2/22-Figure1-1.png) in [Multi-body Orbit Architectures for Lunar South Pole Coverage](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4d23/185a6700af6e111a82017f2c31839d9b2188.pdf)

Comment: @JCRM Thanks! K. Howell's group has better (and smaller) pdf [online here](https://engineering.purdue.edu/people/kathleen.howell.1/Publications/Conferences/2006_AAS_GreOziHowFol.pdf)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry that I'm so late to this, but I worked with the butterfly family quite a lot when I was a student in Professor Howell's group so I feel compelled to answer! It looks like you found some good resources already, but I can expand a bit and show some more of the family :)

I have quite a few visualizations of the L2 southern butterfly family in the Earth-Moon CRTBP. I've uploaded a bunch of videos to a [playlist on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1kgyt_fBDpYrUKXCj0oAqi-djSXsEsc0). I also have a bunch of 3D figures in Plotly which are quite neat but I will hold off on sharing those for the moment. The videos in that playlist detail a few things, including the evolution of the family and what a few of the orbits would actually look like with a spacecraft in them. The family is extensive and becomes quite complex, so the examples I've shown in the videos only cover a small subset of the available motion. Hopefully, though, the examples I did provide will allow you to visualize the rest of the family in your head.

I'll highlight some videos:

- [Evolution of the Butterfly Family, version 1](https://youtu.be/6nevYSp8ClE)
- [Evolution of the Butterfly Family, version 2](https://youtu.be/yN_Fz2poidY)
- [Traversing a Butterfly, example 1](https://youtu.be/up8FBcbOoxk)
- [Traversing a Butterfly, example 2](https://youtu.be/sAuSKIRKT2E)
- [Comparing the Butterflies and Halos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMlcA_WSscQ)

I also detailed the evolution of the family in [my thesis](https://engineering.purdue.edu/people/kathleen.howell.1/Publications/Masters/2019_Bolliger.pdf). In particular, figures 5.8—5.13 detail the evolution of the family. I tried my best to highlight the motion and how it changes, but it's difficult in 2D.

I also recommend [Dan Grebow's thesis](https://engineering.purdue.edu/people/kathleen.howell.1/Publications/Masters/2006_Grebow.pdf), which gives more example orbits and provides initial conditions like you were interested in.

There is so much to talk about. I could go on and on! But hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: `+n!` Jackpot! Oh this is fantastic :-) will go get those theses and spend the weekend poring over them. In the mean time, if you click the three-body and halo-orbit tags under the question you will find more unanswered or partially answered questions, some of which may pique your interest as well. *Thanks!*

Comment: It's really wonderful that you've uploaded those videos to YouTube as well.On behalf of all the readers here *Thank you!*

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If I can clarify anything, feel free to reach out.