# How much delta-v does the Orion spacecraft have?

Tags: delta-v, orion-spacecraft

[Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_(spacecraft)) is intended to transport astronauts around [cis-lunar space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space#Geospace). How much [delta-v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v) performance does it actually have?

Answer (score 9):

### The Answer

Orion (with service module) can use **between 1346 m/s and 1587 m/s** of delta-v.

Here is a solar system delta-v map to get a sense of how much that is:
[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Delta-Vs_for_inner_Solar_System.svg]

(Delta-v map taken from [wikipedia page on delta-v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v))

What follows is the math for determining those values.

### Spacecraft Mass

Capsule Masses:

- Capsule Dry Mass: 9300 kg
- Capsule Wet Mass: 10400 kg
- Capsule Hydrazine Mass: 1100 kg

Service Module Masses:

- Service Module Dry Mass: 6185 kg
- Service Module Wet Mass: 15461 kg
- Service Module Propellant Mass: 9276 kg

Plus 659 kg integration mass? (Found by subtraction component masses from total injected mass on Wikipedia)

Total mass: 26520 kg

Total mass after expending service Module Fuel: 17244

Mass values from
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_(spacecraft)

### Engine Performance

Capsule thrusters:

- [MR-104G thrusters](https://spaceflight101.com/spacecraft/orion/)
- [Hydrazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrazine)
- [Specific Impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse): [220s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrazine#rocket_fuel) (I can't actually find the specific impulse of MR-104G but this value seems pretty typical of hydrazine monopropellants)

Service Module Main Engine:

- [AJ10 Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJ10)
- Nitrogen Tetroxide Oxidizer and Aerozine50 Fuel
- Specific impulse 319s

### The Math

**The [rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) is:**

$\Delta v = \ln(\frac{wet\;mass}{dry\;mass}) \times g \times specific\;impulse$

**Delta-v from the service module, with capsule attached (This is by far the most impactful piece):**

$\ln(\frac{26520\, kg}{17244\, kg}) \times 9.8\, m/s² \times 319\, s = 1346\, m/s$

**Delta-v from the capsule alone:**

$\ln(\frac{10400\, kg}{9300\, kg}) \times 9.8\, m/s² \times 220\, s = 241\, m/s$

**Delta-v from the service module, then the capsule, staying attached:**

$\ln(\frac{26520\, kg}{17244\, kg})\times 9.8\, m/s² \times 319\,s + \ln(\frac{17244\,kg}{16144\,kg}) \times 9.8\,m/s² \times 220\,s = 1488\, m/s $

**Delta-v from the capsule, then the service module, staying attached:**

$\ln(\frac{26520\,kg}{25420\,kg}) \times 9.8\,m/s² \times 220s + \ln(\frac{25420\,kg}{16144\,kg}) \times 9.8\,m/s² \times 319\,s = 1511\,m/s$

**Delta-v from the service module, then ejecting the service module and firing the capsule by itself:**

$\ln(\frac{26520\,kg}{17244\,kg}) \times 9.8\,m/s² \times 319\,s +  \ln(\frac{10400\,kg}{9300\,kg}) \times 9.8\,m/s² \times 220\,s = 1587\,m/s$

Note that I have ignored [cosine losses](https://www.reddit.com/r/KerbalAcademy/comments/25dir3/what_does_cosine_losses_mean/) from the Orion thrusters firing slightly off axis (the capsule walls are at an angle, after all), but I doubt they are substantial.